# My vector can't handle a certain amount of strings

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to read in a text file of strings into a vector like so:

```
ifstream data;
vector<string> set;
string name;

data.open(argv[2]);

while (data >> name) {      
    set.push_back(name);
}
```

This works perfectly with a smaller data set, say with about 10 values, but when I get up into the 200 string area, it crashes into a segmentation fault. I have another function in my program that creates another vector of integer values that works with any number of values in the file. Is there a certain reason that the strings crash my program and is there any way that I can fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it's only strings in your text file? If there's symbols like ^&%$# etc. Then C++ may not know what to do with these when it hits them. To be sure, try with a small set of 10 values, and then copy paste these values over and over in the same text file, try loading in that text file and see if it works fine. If so, then it's a problem within the other text file.

Comment: Yes, I have found that its not actually the size that is causing the crash. I have a function that compares two vectors and deletes the common entries,  and I am hitting the seg fault there. Thanks for your help though!